# If $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $(2a,2b)=(a+b, a-b)$, where $(x,y)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to prove the following assertion:

> "If $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $(2a,2b)=(a+b, a-b)$".

$(x,y)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$. I am trying to prove it by showing that $(a,b) \vert (a+b, a-b)$ and $(a+b, a-b) \vert (a,b)$.

Denote $(a+b, a-b)$ by $d.$ Since $d \vert (a+b)$ and $d \vert (a-b)$ then $d \vert (a+b) + (a-b) = 2a$ and also $d \vert (a+b)-(a-b) = 2b$. This implies that $d \vert (2a,2b) = 2(a,b)$.

The other way of the proof is where I am struggling. Suppose $(a,b) = y$. Since $a$ and $b$ are odd we have that $a=2n+1$ and $b=2m+1$ for some integers $n,m.$ The sum $a+b$ and the difference $a-b$ is therefore even, and also we have that
$a=yr$ and $b=ys$ for some integers $r,s$ so $a+b = y(r+s)$ and $a-b = y(r-s).$ This implies that $y \vert (a+b)$ and $y \vert (a-b)$ which implies that $y \vert (a+b, a-b)$. However, I have not been able to show that $2y \vert (a+b, a-b)$. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: I added an alternative method finishing your proof (it's essentially the same as my first proof but without the cancelling reduction).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you very much! I posted a follow up question after you edited the post, but I wasn't able to tag you in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancelling $\,d = (a,b)\,$ from both sides reduces it to the case where $\,(a,b) = 1.\,\,$  Then it becomes $\, 2 = (a-b,\,a+b)\,$ for $a,b\,$ odd and coprime. Proof: $ $ clearly $\,2\mid a-b,a+b\,$ by $\,a,b\,$ odd.   Conversely $\,c\mid a-b,a+b\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid 2a,2b\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid (2a,2b)=2(a,b)=2.\ $  **QED**

Alternatively: $\,a\!+\!b,\,a\!-\!b\,$ are divisible by the coprimes $\,2\,$ and $\,(a,b)\,$ so also by their product $2(a,b) = (2a,2b),\,$ so $\,(2a,2b)\mid (a\!+\!b,a\!-\!b).\,$ This completes the proof (with your converse).

Comment: Cancelling any gcd to reduce to the coprime case is a common way to simplify *homogeneous* divisibility problems

Comment: Just one little question to the alternative you gave: How do we know that $2$ and $(a,b)$ are coprime? I thought about this solution, but since I couldn't show that $2$ and $(a,b)$ were coprime it didn't work. I really appreciate your thorough response!

Comment: @Thomas $\ (a,b)\,$ is odd since it divides the odd $\,a\ \ $

Comment: of course ! I confused myself by thinking of the general statement "are even and odd numbers coprime?" instead of considering just $2$ and odd numbers.

Comment: @Thomas Though the cancelling method may seem like more work in this specific case, it is very powerful so well-worth learning. I suggest you write it out explicitly using new variables e.g. $\,\bar a = a/d,\  \bar b = b/d\,$ instead of reusing the same variables as I did (after you master the idea then  there is no need to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Let $D=\gcd(2a,2b)$ and $d=\gcd(a+b,a-b)$

Clearly $2\,|\,D$ so let $D=2E$. As you note, $E=\gcd(a,b)$.   It is clear that $2\,|\,d$, and it is clear that $E$ is odd.  To see that $E\,|\,d$ we remark that $E$ must divide both $a$ and $b$, hence $E$ divides $a\pm b$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I am not quite sure that I follow this completely. I follow until "To see that $E \vert d$..." I can understand why $E$ divides both $a$ and $b$. However, it is not clear why $D=2E \vert d$ just because both $2 \vert d$ and $E \vert d$ each on their own. I hope I made my confusion clear :)

Comment: Or is it because $2$ and $E$ are relatively prime ?

Comment: Yes, it's because $2,E$ are relatively prime.  That's a good exercise.  Show that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $m\,|\,A$ and $n\,|\,A$, together imply that $mn\,|\,A$.

Comment: Worth noting:  in this case, life is simpler.  Note that $E\,|\,a-b\implies a-b=E\times k$ for some $k$.  $k$ must be even since $a-b$ is, whence $2E\,|\,a-b$.  Similar for $a+b$.

Comment: I have actually done that earlier, which is what got me thinking about the solution :)  however I am not able to see why $2$ and $E$ are relatively prime. Do you have a chance to elaborate? Really appreciate it.

Comment: $E=\gcd(a,b)$ and both $a$ and $b$ are odd, so $E$ is odd.

Comment: oh of course ! Sorry for the stupid question, I confused myself by noting that it is not the case that all even numbers are coprime with odd numbers instead of just considering 2 and odd numbers. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

$ D=(a,b)$ so that $D|a,\ D|b,\ 2D=(2a,2b)$ and $D$ is odd

Hence $D|a+b,\ D|a-b$ so that $D|(a+b,a-b)$

Since $a+b,\ a-b$ are even, $2D|(a+b,a-b)$

When $D'=2kD|(a+b,a-b),\ k>1$, then
$$2kD=D'|(a+b)-(a-b)=2b
,\ kD|b$$

Similarly, $kD|a$ so that it is a contradiction to $D=(a,b)$

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am not sure that I follow this step: "since $a+b, a-b$ are even, $2D \vert (a+b, a-b)$." Is there any way to write this more pedantically? Sorry if I am being slow.

Comment: $a=a'D,\ b=b'D$ so that $a-b=(a'-b')D$ is even Hence $a'-b'$ is even